# wp_login_form: Redirect to dynamic url according to username

Tags: redirect, login

i need to redirect users after login. I use `wp_login_form` to provide a login form on the frontpage.

After a user entered username and password i'd like to redirect to a custom url, like http://myurl.com/username/ where 'username' is the name the user entered.

Could i somehow filter `login_redirect`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter and set where you want to redirect to which user or role with the plugin [Peter's Login Redirect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/peters-login-redirect/).